# Recyclerview is becoming small after switch Fragments

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-recyclerview

**I have been trying to implement recyclerview in fragment when I switch between the Fragments the reyclerview is reducing in size as shown in the image**

[image: before switching between fragments]

[image: After Switching between fragments]

*The code is given below I did not user recyclerview.setHasFixedSize(true); on purpose because if I use it won't retrieve data from the database making empty recyclerview*

**XML CODE**

```
?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:background="@color/apptheme"
android:orientation="vertical"
tools:context=".ProgrammesAndSubjects.Subjects_Under_ProgrammeFragment">


<TextView
    android:id="@+id/add_subject"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_gravity="end"
    android:layout_marginEnd="@dimen/_7sdp"
    android:layout_marginTop="@dimen/_7sdp"
    android:includeFontPadding="false"
    android:text="Add \n Subjects"
    android:textAlignment="center"
    android:textColor="@color/appcolor"
    android:textSize="@dimen/_12sdp"
    android:textStyle="bold"
    tools:ignore="RtlCompat" />


<ProgressBar
    android:id="@+id/top_class"
    android:layout_width="50dp"
    android:layout_height="50dp"
    android:layout_gravity="center"
    android:outlineSpotShadowColor="@color/white" />


<androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView
    android:id="@+id/recyclerView_classes"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_marginBottom="@dimen/_6sdp"
    android:padding="10dp"

    android:divider="@null"
    android:scrollbars="vertical" />


<ProgressBar
    android:id="@+id/bottomprogressbar_classes"
    android:layout_width="50dp"
    android:layout_height="50dp"
    android:layout_gravity="center"
    android:layout_marginTop="-40dp"
    android:outlineSpotShadowColor="@color/white" />

 </LinearLayout>
```

**JAVA CODE**

```
  @Override
public void onViewCreated(@NonNull View view, @Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onViewCreated(view, savedInstanceState);


    addsubjects = getView().findViewById(R.id.add_subject);
    progressBar = getView().findViewById(R.id.top_class);
    bottomProgressbar = getView().findViewById(R.id.bottomprogressbar_classes);
    recyclerView = getView().findViewById(R.id.recyclerView_classes);

    RecyclerView.LayoutManager mlayoutManager = new LinearLayoutManager(getContext());

    recyclerView.setLayoutManager(mlayoutManager);

}
```

**It has a normal adapter which has been set to it **

Answer (score 0):

> when I switch between the Fragments the reyclerview is reducing in size Fragments the reyclerview is reducing in size

It's not the `recyclerView` that is resizing, it's the page of `viewPager` which is getting resized when you switch to a different page. After you switch to the `Student's` page it resizes to the size of that, and then its size sticks to that and doesn't change back to the full height.

---

To fix this, you have to set the height of the page manually, as `viewPager` doesn't do it on its own.

As you haven't tagged any `viewPager` tag, I'm expecting it to be a `ViewPager2`. You can use `setPageTransformer` method in `ViewPager2` to set the new size of the page.

```
viewPager2.setPageTransformer((page, position) -> page.post(() -> {
            int wMeasureSpec = View.MeasureSpec
                    .makeMeasureSpec(page.getWidth(), View.MeasureSpec.EXACTLY);

            int hMeasureSpec = View.MeasureSpec
                    .makeMeasureSpec(0, View.MeasureSpec.UNSPECIFIED);

            page.measure(wMeasureSpec, hMeasureSpec);
            ViewGroup.LayoutParams layoutParams = viewPager2.getLayoutParams();
            layoutParams.height = page.getMeasuredHeight();
            viewPager2.setLayoutParams (layoutParams);
            viewPager2.invalidate();
        }));
```